# Extracting code using regex in Autohotkey

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I am trying to extract the R code from comments using Autohotkey (i.e., "variable <- 123", the 4th line without the starting "#"). The sample text is:

```
# this is comment 1
# this is comment 2
# this is comment n
variable <- 123
```

I tried the following regex, but didn't work as I expected. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
^(?<!#)(.*?)$
```

[The results in AHK Regex tester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1LpK.png)

Comment: What do you mean R code? You're just matching lines without comments?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to extract the lines without the starting "#".

Comment: Might be worth it to not use regex. I'm not really seeing any reason to use regex here. Could easily just parse each line, and if the line starts with `#`, discard it. I'd assume this would be much more efficient than regex as well. Don't quote me on that though.

Comment: @0x464e You're right, it *would* be more efficient to simply remove lines that start with a hash. The pattern I provided below assumes no whitespace or padding before the hash per the OP's example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
^[^#\n]+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Matches the start of a new line or string
- `[^#\n]` Matches a character that is not a hash or new line

  - `+` Matches one or more of the above token
- `$` Matches the end of line or string

Comment: Thanks. It works in Javascript/Python regex: https://regex101.com/r/5EdSZJ/1, however, not in Autohotkey regex, any idea?

Comment: Make sure you have multiline flag enabled and also check out my edited answer.